# Groovy script for deleting Jenkins global credentials user via ID (not username)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to delete a credential that is stored in the Global Credentials store using a .groovy script.  I want to search and delete by the ID value NOT the username.

Here is my code so far:

```
import hudson.model.User

def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null
)


//ID I intend on deleting
id_name ='test-id-name'


//here we cycle through all the credentials until we find the intended id
for (c in creds) {
  if (c.id == id_name){
    println("Found existing ID")
    //here we attempt to delete  by id
    User u = User.get(id_name)
    u.delete()
  }
}
```

When I run the code, it prints the line saying that it found the ID but it doesnt actually delete.  I dont get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code as an example: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/deleteAllGlobalCredentials.groovy

The following code worked.

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain

def credentialsStore = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0].getStore()
allCreds = credentialsStore.getCredentials(Domain.global())

//ID we intend on deleting
id_name ='test-id-name'

//here we cycle through all the credentials until we find the intended id
allCreds.each{

  //if we find the intended ID, delete it
  if (it.id == id_name){
    println ("Found ID")
    credentialsStore.removeCredentials(Domain.global(), it)
  }
}
```

I'm definitely open to suggestions if someone thinks this code can be better optimized.

Comment: Above script is running successfully but it is not deleting the user